# VB.Net Finding class ID to click when it's buried in the DOM

Tags: css, vb.net, class, dom, invokemember

[Example of the tree I'm dealing with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfCab.jpg)

I am trying to click the 'followers' button on an IG account I run to see see the new users who have followed me automatically. (The example in the included picture is not my account for privacy reasons) I can find the class ID, but using something like

```
 Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = webBrowse.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("class") = "g47sy " Then
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

returns nothing for me... I know it's because this class is buried in JS and then further down the line. I can't for the life of me figure out how to check the elements of something buried so far in..

Any help would be super appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `GetElementsByTagName()` where the TAG name is `SPAN`, Then `.GetAttribute("className")`, not `"class"`. Using LINQ, you can just add a `.Where` or `FirstOrDefault` clause to the collection returned by `GetElementsByTagName()` to single one out directly.

Comment: Thank's so much! I was able to figure it out with your help. I need to click on that element which wasn't working. I had to give it an id to be able to click it.

`webpageelement.setattribute("id", "WhateverName")`

Comment: I can't say I know how to use LINQ yet, but will try to figure that out.

Comment: You don't need to give it an ID first. If you have located the element just call `InvokeMember("click")` on it like you already do. What you need to change in your code is to check the **`className`** attribute rather than `class`, and correct the casing of the last two letters (it's `g47SY` rather than `g47sy`).

Answer (score 0):

Posted by Jimi in comments:

GetElementsByTagName() where the TAG name is SPAN, Then .GetAttribute("className"), not "class". Using LINQ, you can just add a .Where or FirstOrDefault clause to the collection returned by GetElementsByTagName() to single one out directly. – Jimi 12 hours ago